# How to rename a directory in a specific way. BASH

Tags: linux, bash, directory

I have a directory with a name **20190606_151020**. I want to rename it in **files_2019-06-06_15-10-20**. In the future I won't know the current directory name, but it will be the only directory there, and I also know that I need to make a prefix **files_** and after **2019** should be a **-**.

How could I do it in a BASH script?

I am very bad in working with strings in bash:(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you mean something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

# find the special directory
name="$(find . -type d -printf %P)"

# split name into parts
year="${name:0:4}"
month="${name:4:2}"
day="${name:6:2}"
hour="${name:9:2}"
min="${name:11:2}"
sec="${name:13:2}"

# rename directory
mv "$name" "files_${year}-${month}-${day}_${hour}-${min}-${sec}"
```

**usage**

Go into that directory where your special dirctory exists and start
the script.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you a lot. I've accepted your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the desired output using awk.

```
echo "20190606_151020" | awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="4 2 2 3 2 2"}{print "file_"$1"-"$2"-"$3$4"-"$5"-"$6}'
```

[image: The sample output is shown below]